# Need Help with Metal Texture Wrapping Issue in Blender

Tags: texturing, materials

As a newcomer to Blender, I'm facing difficulty understanding why the metal texture on my object doesn't wrap smoothly, unlike another similar object that someone else textured for me.

I'm using the same texture in the same .blend file. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I would like it to look like this:
[image]

but instead it looks like this where you can see the individual torus faces:
[image]
The geometry looks very similar.
[image]

## Update

Adding `shade smooth` and `autosmooth` as @L0Lock suggested got me pretty much all the way there:

[image]

my Shader tab for the material in question for completeness:
[image]

Any suggestions on how to further improve the appearance of the threads so they are completely smoothed like they where machined?
[image]

Comment: You mention a metal texture, but all I see is a reflective material with what I guess is the reflections of the environment texture from the viewport's material shading mode. Though your issue looks more like a geometry concern, in object mode try using Right click > Shade smooth, check whether [autosmooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/structure.html#properties) is enabled (and if it is, make sure the angle setting is at least 30) and if not working, try adding a Weld modifier. Otherwise, could you provide a screenshot of your shader nodes please?

Comment: Normal map strength that is too high can also have similar effects

Comment: Thank you @L0Lock, that was super helpful! I've updated my question with the results after smoothing and included a screenshot of the shader nodes for this metal material. Any more tips would be amazing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can set the object's shading to Smooth via the <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> menu.

I like to use the Shade Auto Smooth on shapes like yours because instead of smoothing everything, it will keep the sharp corners flat shaded:

[image]

Then, if you have sharp edges that you want to smooth, you can either:

1. Crank up your object's auto smooth angle under Properties Editor > Object Data tab > Normals Panel:
   [image]
   But it will affect the whole object.
   [image]
2. Use a Bevel modifier (set to either target an angle or a vertex group) to change a given part of geometry:
   [image]

Comment: awesome! thanks so much!

Comment: My pleasure :) Please use the vote buttons at the top of an answer to mark it helpful, and even click the ✔️ button if it's what answered your question.